# Recording a maze path solution with a stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, maze

I am to generate a solution to a maze using a linked list implementation of a stack in some way. The maze is read in from a .txt file and consists of 0's for open spaces and 1's for walls. [image]
<- Pretty sure an exit must be in the bottom row? So those three 0's?

The algorithm I am attempting to use is:

```
While Not At End
    If Can Go North
        Go North
    ElseIf Can Go East
        Go East
    ElseIf Can Go South
        Go South
    ElseIf Can Go West 
        Go West
    EndIf
Wend
```

The way I've been attempting it relied on the ++ operations executing within an array index. I was unaware the array subscript operator [ took precedence over ++ so now I need to rethink a work around. Before doing so, I want to make sure this method will even work in first place. Could anyone take a look at my algo code thus far and provide some feed back? (Note: I still need to add in some code to track paths taken to avoid some type of infinite loop)

```
bool notSolved = true;
        int path = 0;
        row = 0;
        col = 0;

        rowStack.push(row);
        colStack.push(col);

        while (notSolved){

        //(from perspective of person looking at maze on screen)
        if (maze[row--][col] == 0){//if you can go up, go up
        rowStack.push(row);
        colStack.push(col);
        path++;
        }
        else if (maze[row][col++] == 0){//else if you can go right, go right
        rowStack.push(row);
        colStack.push(col);
        path++;
        }
        else if (maze[row++][col] == 0){//else if you can go down, go down
        rowStack.push(row);
        colStack.push(col);
        path++;
        }
        else if (maze[row][col--] == 0){//else if you can go left, go left
        rowStack.push(row);
        colStack.push(col);
        path++;
        }

            if((maze[row][col] == 0) && (row == (size - 1))){//if we reached an exit
                cout << "Solution Path:" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < path; i++){
                    cout << "row:" << rowStack.top() << " col:" << colStack.top() << endl;
                    rowStack.pop();
                    colStack.pop();
                }
            notSolved = false;
            }
        }
```

Problem with executing [ before ++:
[image]

Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: recursion is your friend on this one.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I don't think that algorithm is particularly good, for instance if you run into the right wall while in a horizontal tunnel, you'll bounce back and forth right to left forever.

Comment: @Erix Searching breadth-first works better on mazes, so in this case a queue might be a better 'friend' than recursion. Even if you decide to go depth-first, you might be better off with a stack and a "while" loop instead of recursion. Since the search space grows as N^2, the danger of overflowing the stack in a recursive call becomes very real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm will not work in certain mazes that have circular paths: once you get into one of these, you'll be going in circles. To fix this, you need to add a boolean array visited[R][C][DIR], where DIR is a number from zero to three representing a direction. When you leave cell [r][c] in the direction [d], set visited[r][c][d] to true. Next time you visit the same cell, see if you have left it in the same direction before; if you did, skip that direction, and go for the next one down the line.

Comment: Hmm, I think I got that visited array working, but I am experiencing problems. Is there a better way to implement it in the if statements Here is the problem:http://imgur.com/5rstN, goes right, down, right, right, hits wall then turns around and gets stuck. Here is my new code:http://pastebin.com/uhp9MKfc

Comment: @mwmnj The code for checking if you've been at a spot looks good, now you need to implement backtracking, a fancy name for "what to do when you're stuck". In your case, you need to pop the last step from your rowStack/colStack, go back to the previous cell, and continue to the next direction you haven't tried before.

Comment: hmm, My initial thought is adding an else at the end: `else{//if stuck
        rowStack.pop();
        colStack.pop();
        row = rowStack.top();
        col = colStack.top();
        }` But now all that seems to do is pop every previous step off the top of the stack until it is empty

Comment: @mwmnj You need to look at the top before calling pop. You also need to check if the stack is empty before popping it. Finally, you need to enclose your ifs in a loop, because once you backtracked, you need to continue moving in the next direction that you have not tried.

Comment: What do I need to look at before calling pop? What I am attempting to do is have it pop the stacks and then reassign row and col to the previous spaces value so that it will go and try whatever direction it hasn't tried yet. My if statements are enclosed in a loop: Wnotsolved: http://pastebin.com/VSE2qBDu

Comment: @mwmnj You need to reorder calls of pop and top, like this: `else{ row = rowStack.top(); col = colStack.top(); rowStack.pop(); colStack.pop(); }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5472/discussion-between-mwmnj-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

`++` and `--` actually modify the row / col variables. I think you want to do `maze[row - 1][col] == 0` and then once you've moved, update your row position.